# Not connecting to the network properly

Tags: networking

When I log into Ubuntu it will sometimes open the browser but then stops working.  When I check the network it says I'm using a wifi hotspot, which I have not set it up to do.  I'm using Ubuntu 15.10.  I have a Dell Inspiron One 2330 Computer.  I also cannot get it to recognize my printer.  An Epson WP-4020.